# Spring boot: Password authentication failed for user "postgres "

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm making a simple rest and crud via jpa and I use postgres.

When I run the code I saw this line:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres "
......
```

This is my `application.properties`:

```
server.port=1408

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/weebjournal
spring.datasource.username=postgres 
spring.datasource.password=[REDACTED]
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You have a whitespace behind username :  "postgres "